# Copying a filename on the same line to the end of the line

Tags: vim, search, replacement

I have the following lines in VIM:

```
<img src="file01.jpg" / >
<img src="file02.jpg" / >
<img src="file03.jpg" / >
```

And I would like to add the filename of each jpg to the end of each line like this:

```
<img src="file01.jpg" / > file01.jpg
<img src="file02.jpg" / > file02.jpg
<img src="file03.jpg" / > file03.jpg
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no single best way.

A way to do it is:

```
:1,$s/\(file.*jpg\)\(.*\)/\1\2 \1
```

Another way is

```
:map q 0t"  yt"A ^[pj
```

and pres `q` 3 times (note: enter `^[` as control-V escape)

You can also add  `file01.jpg` to each line, (`A` `file01.jpg` escape `j` `.` `j` `.`) and replace the `01` with `02` etc. (`:0` enter `/01` enter `c2`  `02` escape `n` etc.)

And I'm sure there are many more ways.

Comment: Be careful with overriding default commands. `:help q` is pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather elegant method:

```
f"yi"A <C-r>"
```

Where…

- `f"` moves the cursor to the first `"` on the line,
- `yi"` yanks whatever is between the current double quotes to the unnamed register,
- `A` enters insert mode at the end of the line,
- inserts a space,
- `<C-r>"` inserts the content of the unnamed register.

You can record it this way:

```
qq
f"yi"A <C-r>"
q
```

which leaves you with:

```
<img src="file01.jpg" / > file01.jpg
<img src="file02.jpg" / >
<img src="file03.jpg" / >
```

and play it back on the rest of the lines this way:

```
:+,$norm @q
```

Now, recording macros is very powerful and useful but I think that it requires a bit too much planning. Over the years I switched almost entirely to writing and executing my macros directly:

```
:%norm f"yi"A ^R"
```

which I find easier to improvise on the spot. `^R` is obtained by pressing `<C-v><C-r>`.